# Making the axis lines on a D3 graph disappear

Tags: javascript, web, d3.js

I created a graph shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/URqLi.jpg, but am curious how to make the X and Y axis ticks and lines disappear.

Going for a cleaner look, figured I'd get rid of them!

```
const margin2 = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 60, left: 250}
const width2 = 1000 - margin2.left - margin2.right
const graphWidth2 = 600-margin2.left - margin2.right
const graphHeight2 = 900 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom
const height2 = 370 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom


const svg2 = d3.select(".line").append("svg").attr("width", width2 + margin2.left + margin2.right)
.attr("height", height2 + margin2.top + margin2.bottom)
.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left+148},${margin.top})`)


d3.json("./data/linedata.json").then(function(data) {

    const x2 = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([ 0, width2])

    svg2.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x2)
    .tickFormat(d => d + "%"))
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr('class', 'xaxis')
    .attr("transform", "translate(12,0)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")

    const y2 = d3.scaleBand().range([ 0, height2 ])
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.desc; })).padding(.2)

    svg2.append("g").attr('class', 'xaxis')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y2)).style("font-family","Pluto Sans").style("font-size","16")

    svg2.selectAll("myGraph").data(data).enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x",x2(0))
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y2(d.desc)})
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x2(d.total)})
    .attr("height", y2.bandwidth())


})
```

Comment: You want the labels but not the ticks marks / axis line right?

Comment: Hi Andrew - yes that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axis is comprised of text, line, and path elements. If you want to remove the path and line elements, and have no other path or line elements elsewhere, you could simply select them and remove them:

```
 d3.selectAll("path,line").remove();
```

However, you could also keep a reference for your parent `g` elements (especially if there are other elements that are paths or lines elsewhere), and use `parentSelection.selectAll("path,line").remove();` instead, as I've done below:

```js
var width = 500, height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
  
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,100])
  .range([0,width])
  
var axis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate("+[0,width/2]+")");
 
axis.call(d3.axisBottom(scale));

axis.selectAll("path,line")
   .style("opacity",1)
   .transition()
   .duration(2000)
   .style("opacity",0)
   .remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The axis generator also gives classes to the ticks and the paths, so you could also select elements referencing the class names:

```js
var width = 500, height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
  
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,100])
  .range([0,width])
  
var axis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate("+[0,width/2]+")");
 
axis.call(d3.axisBottom(scale));

axis.selectAll(".domain,.tick>line")
   .style("opacity",1)
   .transition()
   .duration(2000)
   .style("opacity",0)
   .remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```